# Friend and strangers at at a meeting problem

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

> There are 2020 people present at a meeting. Every two people are either friends to each other
>   or strangers to each other. We know that each person has the same number of friends at the meeting, which
>   is n. Find the minimum value of n such that among these 2020 people, we can always find four people
>   A, B, C, D such that every two of four people are friends to each other.

I think it has to do with graph theory, but i dont see how.

Idea:
Every line that represents friends would be blue and every line that represents strangers would be red.
The graph would have 2020 vertices, and the problem would be to find the minimum value of n such that among the lines connecting all vertices, we can always find a cuadrilateral with its sides and diagonals, all blue.

From COFFEE contest problem 3 (already ended).

Comment: A link to the origin of the problem would be nice. Also, some more effort would go a long way; you're thinking graph theory. What's the graph? What do the vertices and edges represent, and then what is the question in terms of graphs?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347672/possible-clique-numbers-of-a-regular-graph) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If $n \leq 1346$, the graph (whose vertices are people and edges are between friends) could be a subgraph of the complete tripartite graph $K_{673,673,674}$ with parts having 673, 673, and 674 vertices. (In the complete tripartite graph, vertices in the two smaller parts have degree 1347, and vertices in the big part have degree 1346.)

This graph has no 4-clique, so we can't find four people who are mutually friends.

If $n \geq 1347$, the graph has more edges than $K_{673,673,674}$, which by [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) has the maximal number of edges in a 4-clique-free graph on 2020 vertices. So then we can find four such mutual friends.